# Cassandra OutOfMemoryError during range query

Tags: cassandra

I have a table that contains 1MB blobs.

CREATE TABLE blobs_1 (
  key text,
  version bigint,
  chunk int,
  object_blob blob,
  object_size int,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, version, chunk)
)

Each lob is spread on about 100 chunks.
The following query results in OutOfMemory errors:

select object_size from blobs_1 where key = 'key1' and version = 1;

Here is the error:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.readBytes(RandomAccessReader.java:344)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:392)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:355)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserializeColumnBody(ColumnSerializer.java:124)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.OnDiskAtom$Serializer.deserializeFromSSTable(OnDiskAtom.java:85)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:75)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:64)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:88)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:37)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.hasNext(SSTableSliceIterator.java:82)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.LazyColumnIterator.computeNext(LazyColumnIterator.java:82)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.LazyColumnIterator.computeNext(LazyColumnIterator.java:59)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.getNext(QueryFilter.java:157)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.hasNext(QueryFilter.java:140)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:144)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.advance(MergeIterator.java:123)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:97)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:185)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:122)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIteratorFactory$2.getReduced(RowIteratorFactory.java:101)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIteratorFactory$2.getReduced(RowIteratorFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.consume(MergeIterator.java:115)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:98)

Comment: This occurs on 2.0.2. It is frustrating that a single query crashes the server so easily.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reduce your page size.  The default paging size is meant for normal small columns/rows.  For large blobs you need to shrink the paging size down.

https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.java#L234

Comment: I've also created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6492 to automate this.

Comment: Since this occurs in cqlsh the java-driver won't help much. So, there is no way to avoid fetching the blobs if I only need the object_size? I could move "object_size" to another table but the same problem occurs when I try to fetch "chunk" which is part of the primary key, and this cannot be moved to another table.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because Cassandra deserializes the more data than necessary upon read of a single column of a table (at least, Cassandra 1.2, maybe this has been improved in 2.0 branch).

To fix the problem you may introduce a separate table for metadata (sizes, etc). It will slow down writes a bit, but vastly improve read performance.